# Appropriate HTTP Header to track original request after redirect?

Tags: apache, http

Anyone aware of an existing HTTP Header that could be appropriately used to track the original Host/URI requested when doing a 3xx redirect?  This would allow the target server (in the Location header) to do something with it.

The Forwarded and Origin headers aren't appropriate in this case.

We'll do something Custom if no pseudo standard here...

Comment: Is the response going to a standard browser or a custom client?  A standard browser won't be passing along any header you set to the target server.

Comment: That's a good point.  Duh.